# Disable USB's including mouse and keyboard, enable with key combo

Tags: windows-7, usb, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

I have a specific scenario where I have a computer displaying cameras on screen but the operators keep plugging USB's and keyboard/mouse into it. I am aware that I can disable the USB storage functionality quite easily but I also need to disable the Keyboard and Mouse for them to stop moving tiles and screwing around with the computer. If I completely disable all USB ports, that would be alright until I needed to access it myself with a keyboard and mouse. So I was wondering if there was a way I could have it so HID's don't work until the password is entered? I'll have to write a mini script and insert it in the startup folder but I am not sure what to write.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 2):

There is a two fold solution to this problem:

### Hardware Solution

USB locks are available in the market which are inexpensive
[image: Hardware USB lock]
You can install them and take the key (the thing with which you push the lock inside the USB ports) away (or secure it under lock & key).
This protects from physical access to the ports and also saves you from modifying the configuration of the system under question.

---

### Software Solution

START -> REGEDIT ->HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlset\services\
Select USBSTOR. Change the value of start to 4 (HEX). See image below.
[image]
This approach only disables the storage devices that can be connected to the PC. Hence can be ineffective against keyboard and mouse usage.

I'd recommend that you mix both solutions and use to obtain highest possible control.

Comment: Thanks Prasanna, I had already seen these options. I am looking for a more in depth software or an added step after the HID driver is installed. I dont want to have to buy a key for every port (4x usb ports) per computer not only because of cost but also because of the chances that key getting lost in said warehouse is too high.. I understand my solution is quite custom but I feel it will be the most efficient.

Answer (score 2):

The best option for your situation would probably be to disable the USB controllers in device manager. When you need to access the computer, access it from the network using a remote control tool (teamviewer, LMI, VNC, your RMM, etc.), rather than plugging in a keyboard/mouse physically.

Answer (score 1):

To really disable the USB ports, you must:

1. Physically remove them, or fill them with epoxy.  I'm sure those little plastic things can be pried out.
2. Physically lock the computer casing to prevent access, or place the computer in a locked room - and then make arrangements for when there is a power blip and the computer needs to be rebooted.  You don't mind making service calls at 3AM, do you?

Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

I have made this mode many times: 
Just splice into your keyboard's cable near the keyboard, cut the red wire and splice in a SPST switch with enough length place it somewhere convenient, and problem solved. I just hot glue mine to the keyboard. This is a good solution for cats and kids, not people who want to use your computer. For that I would use a log-in. Computer still runs, but no changes can be made without a login.

Another software solution is [This:](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11570/disable-the-keyboard-with-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-windows/) which I am about to install.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but useless in case the "user" brings his own keyboard.